Conditional delete values of variables
Suppose I have the following:
data DB;
  input ID $ Class1  Class2  Class3  Index;
cards;
0001  .   .    .   2
0001  .   .    .   2
0001  .   3.2  .   1
0001  .   3.2 5.3  .
0002 2.1  .    .   1
0002 2.1  0.2  .   .
0002  .   3.2  .   1
0002  .   3.2  1.1 .
;


Is there a way to get the following?
data DB1;
  input ID $ Class1  Class2  Class3  Index;
cards;
0001  .   .    .   2
0001  .   .    .   2
0001  .   3.2  .   1
0001  .   .   5.3  .
0002 2.1  .    .   1
0002  .    0.2  .  .
0002  .   3.2  .   1
0002  .    .  1.1  .
;


In other words when Index = . then delete the replicated value for each Class: (the second of replicated values by ID but only at line where Index = .).

How many Class variables do you have? Just the 3?

Thank you very much for your comment. There are 7 total classes.

Can you explain more what this data means? How did you end up with data that you want to remove?  Why do want to remove that data?

Try this. And comment out the Drop Statement if you want to understand the logic.
data want;

   set DB;
   by ID;

   array lag_{3};
   array c{*} class:;

   lag_index = ifn(first.ID, ., lag(Index));

   if lag_index = 1 then do;
      do i = 1 to dim(lag_);
         if lag_[i] = c[i] then c[i] = .;
      end;
   end;

   output;

   do i = 1 to dim(lag_);
      lag_[i] = c[i];
   end;

   retain lag_:;
   drop lag_: i lag_index;

run;

Result:
ID    Class1  Class2  Class3  Index
0001  .       .       .       2
0001  .       .       .       2
0001  .       3.2     .       1
0001  .       .       5.3     .
0002  2.1     .       .       1
0002  .       0.2     .       .
0002  .       3.2     .       1
0002  .       .       1.1     .


Thank you very much for your precious help. One question: what if IDs are not always by groups of 4? In other words here IDs are 40001, 40002 but this is not a rule. I have a variable number of ID replicates.

The number of rows within each ID doesn't matter in this example.

So it runs also with different numbers of rows per ID? My question is because of lag(3). It is not exactly clear to me.Thank you very much!

Ah sure. The array lag_{3} simply creates three variables to hold the lagged values of each of the Class Variables. You should make that array lag_{7} if you have seven Class variables. Comment out the Drop Statement. Then it makes much more sense :-)

If I understand correctly, you want to set a CLASS variable to missing if the current record has INDEX=. and the immediately preceding record has INDEX=1 and an identical value for the CLASS variable.  If that is correct, then
data want (drop=_:);
  set db;
  by id;
  array CL class: ;
  _lgindex=ifn(first.id,.,lag(index));
  do over CL;
    if CL=lag(CL) and _lgindex=1 and first.ID=0 then CL=.;
  end;
run;

